# Database keeps reverting to previous date

Tags: python, django, heroku

So, I'm writing this with the caveat that I'm well-aware you're going to ask for more information, but I don't know yet what to put.

I have a django-app that's powering a personal website, which has a simple message board for people to leave me notes about how awesome I am.  Now, I've had a lot of trouble with this app in general and have gone back and forth through a lot of git-ness, which is what I'm guessing maybe somehow caused this problem.

Somehow, my data is continually being replaced with a specific snapshot of my database.  When I checked it this morning, it had the ten old dummy test messages, and one new real one.  I replied to the new real one, deleted the dummy test ones, and everything looked fine.  I didn't touch the app again for the day.  When I went to check it again just now, the new message was gone and the dummy ones were back.

It's deployed via Heroku and written in Python 2.7 and Django 1.6.  The site is live at www.wienerwedding.com/guestbook/.

Here's my settings.py file, which is the only guess I can make about what might be an issue.
If you tell me what might be helpful to look at, I'll include it.

```
# Django settings for wedding project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    ('xxx', 'xxxx@gmail.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {

        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'wedding.db',


    }
}
# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

    # Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
if(DEBUG != True):
    import dj_database_url
    DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')


TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users/paulnichols/code/wedding/mainsite/static/images/photoalbum/'

MEDIA_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/photos/'

import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'mainsite/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxxxx'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django_user_agents.middleware.UserAgentMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'wedding.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'wedding.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    'mainsite/templates',
    'quiz/templates',
    'photoalbum/templates',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'mainsite',
    'quiz',
    'photoalbum',
    'django_google_maps',
    'django_user_agents',
    'south',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: is the wedding.db file by any chance being tracked by git? if so you may want to stop tracking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have DEBUG set to True, which according to that code means that you will always be using the sqlite db file which is probably being uploaded along with your app, rather than Heroku's Postgres setup. Either ensure that DEBUG is false, and/or use another environment variable to determine whether to use the development db or not.